# XML parsing with DOM

Tags: java, android

I am parsing xml file from SDcard and display it in textview. whenever i tried to access, nothing will displayed

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/jokes.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(in);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("jokes");

for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {
    Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);
    System.out.println("" + fstNode);
    if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;
        NodeList fstNmElmntLst = (NodeList) fstElmnt.getChild("item");
        Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
        NodeList fstNm = ((Node) fstNmElmnt).getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("Number of joke description : "+ ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

    }
}
```

This is the code which i did to parse xml file from sdcard. can anyone tell where i made a mistake or if you have better option pls let me know.

Comment: if nothing is displayed then your loop is not executing...if your loop is not executing then the search for the "jokes" tag is failing.....if your search for "jokes" is failing...then i have no idea unless i see the xml input

Comment: `<jokes>

     <item title="Joke1" description=""></item>
    <item title="joke2" description=""></item>
     <item title="joke3 " description=""></item>
     <item title="joke4" description=""></item>
     <item title="joke5" description="RAM"></item>
</jokes>
`This is my xml file

Comment: Also while stepping thru the code in debug mode, let us know what you get. For example, what is the nodeLst length.

Comment: Yes when i debug, the length show 5. but i am getting this exception `org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl`

Comment: And what is your stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace is 0. Also i am getting org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl"exception.

Comment: If loop will not iterate till the loop end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your loop:

```
for (int s = 0; s < nodeList.getLength(); s++)
{
    Node firstNode = nodeList.item(s);
    NodeList nodes = firstNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        //print node info
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just import wrong class because there is no method called "getChild" in org.w3c.dom.Element. 
Please import "org.w3c.dom.Element;" in stead of "import android.sax.Element;"